# What's the singular for "shorts"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

When speaking of the article of clothing called "shorts", I know that it is incorrect to construct a sentence like this:

> I wish to buy a shorts.

Instead, it should be constructed like this:

> I wish to buy a *pair of* shorts.

Is this the only correct construction, or is there another way to express this?

Comment: This is a _dual_ noun; not singular, not plural (though it takes plural agreement). Dual nominals describe things that come in two, like body parts and clothes for them, scissors, clippers, and other dualistic things. Some languages have special forms for the dual; in English we just have special dual words like _shorts, gloves, mittens, suspenders, pants, trousers, socks, panties, shoes, couple, pair,_ and _both_. Some exist in the singular, like _sock, shoe_, and _glove_; most don't.

Comment: @JohnLawler That garments of the trews variety are, unlike those which clothe the extremities, exclusively plural is probably attributable to the infrequency of losing just one pant.

Comment: But notice that the shorter the leg extension is, the less strong the duality is, until all one is left with is a topological duality -- two small holes and one larger one. That's why _panty_ is so common in the same sense as _panties_ for female trews -- should they be spelled "trouze", I wonder? I haven't looked it up, but I would guess that the use of singular _panty_ in _panty()hose_ has helped it along. In the US, at least, it seems impressionistically (with, admittedly, a small data set) to be about as common as the plural.

Answer (score 5):

I think the singular is the same for each of: socks, gloves, pants, shorts.

e.g.: *a pair of socks*,  *a pair of gloves*, *a pair of pants*, *a pair of shorts*.

Comment: I would think I could buy some shorts too

Comment: In this usage, yes, but notice that you can talk about "a sock" or "a glove" in a way that you can not for "a short" or "a pant" (both of which are uses that have a very different, non-clothes-related meaning).

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, "some shorts" or "some pants" is OK, but is a vague, usually non-singular amount.

Comment: Supplementing @DanD's answer, in British English, the same as for "trousers":
>*a pair of trousers*; *some trousers*. BrE *trousers* = AmE *pants* BrE *pants* = *underpants*

Comment: I believe certain upscale stores nowadays may talk of *a pant*...  "Would Madam like to look at a pant to go with that blouse?"

Comment: @GEdgar There's a similar linguistic fashion in Hebrew as well. Hebrew has a grammatical form for things that come in pair, such as a pair of pants, but I hear a lot of usage of the singular form for a single item, just like your example.

Answer (score 4):

The term *shorts* referring to garments appears to be derived from the term *[short pants](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shorts)* dating from the 1800s.

The use of the term in the plural appears to follow the usage of *pants*. While the word *pant* can be singular, it is most commonly found in the [plural](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pant).

The word *pants* itself is derived from *pantaloons*, which is also most commonly found in [plural form](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantaloon).  The word *[pantaloons](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pantaloon?q=pantaloons)* to signify a type of trousers is derived from a character in sixteenth century Italian Comedia dell' arte, the archetype of which was named *Pantalone* or *[Pantaleone](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pantaloons&searchmode=none)* who wore long, baggy trousers. How this came to be used in the plural seems obscure.

As a plural noun, *shorts* does not take a singlular article, such as *a*.  It can be used with *the*, which can refer to singular or plural nouns. You can say

> I want to buy the shorts (a particular pair)
>
> I want to buy shorts (in general)
>
> I want to buy some shorts (which may be one or more pair), or
>
> I want to buy a pair of shorts